# combining two second order growth functions

Tags: nonlinear-regression, function

I have two second order growth functions of the form Y =  (K1 * Yeq^2 * x) / (1 + K1 * Yeq * x) and Z =  (K2 * Zeq1^2 * x) / (1 + K2 * Zeq * x), with both Y and Z having an inhibitory effect on each other. Yeq is the equilibrium constant for Y, and K1 is the rate constant for Y. Zeq is the equilibrium constant for Z and K2 is the rate constant for Z.

The models were created from three sets of data, one for Y and x alone, Z and x alone and one for Y, Z and x. Is there a way of combining these two functions so that the function for Y takes onto account the inhibitory effect of Z, and so that the function for Z takes into account the inhibitory effects for Y.

K1 = 0.5 when Z is absent
K1 = 0.12 When Z is present
Yeq = 12 when Z is absent
Yeq = 8 when Z is present

K2 = 0.6 when Y is absent
K2 = 0.4 when Y is present
Zeq = 9 when Y is absent
Zeq = 7 when is absent

x ranges from 0 to 10